# binary indicator "if statement" that works for maximize and minimize

Tags: linear-programming

I am trying to create a binary indicator, such that the indicator `y==1 if x > -0.5` and otherwise, `y==0 if x <= -0.5`.  Right now, I have a working implementation if my objective is to minimize:

```
var y binary; 
param M := 100; 
var z; 

param x := -0.49; 

subto zval: 
  z <= 5; 

subto a: 
  M * y - 0.5 >= x; 

minimize obj: z;
```

However, if I maximize instead, then `y` will be 1 regardless of the value of x.  Is there a way to re-write this in a way that will work for both maximizing and minimizing as the objective function?

Comment: Your problem is not clear to me, because the values of `x` and `y` have no influence on the value of `z` trough any constraint. From your formulation, the solution with `y=1` is optimal wether you minimize or you maximize the objective, since the constraint `a` will automatically be verified if `y=1` (it seems that _by chance_, the solver did choose the solution `y=0` in the case `x <= -0.5`, but the other one would have been correct too).

Comment: Generally, the answer will be _no_, I'm afraid. Those kind of reformulation with big `M` constant rely on the existence of a "sense" of optimization to choose the correct value. In your exemple, since the constraint is satisfied automatically if `y=1`, you must add an "interest" for `y=0`, to make sure that if both values are feasible, `y=0` will be selected. Clearly, it won't be possible to do this with a minimization and maximization problem for the same objective function, since the objective value should either decrease or increase with the value of `y` because of this.